# probability of getting an ace and a king.

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

1) we get a uniformly random hand of 2 cards from a standard deck of 52 cards. Determine the probability that this hand contains an ace and a king.

2) We get a uniformly random hand of 2 cards from the 13 spades. Determine the probability that this hand contains an ace and a king.

---> for first part i believe the sample space is c(52,2). and if A is the set of all elements of S (2 hand) that contains an ace and a king then |A|=16( since 4 ways to choose ace and 4 ways to choose a king)

Am i in correct direction? please help me in explaining this.

Comment: That is correct; can you see how to apply that to the second case?

Comment: so i got 0.012 for first one. i hope its correct.

Comment: for second one. sample space is c(13,2). and |A|= 1 (there are 1 way to choose ace and one way to choose king from 13 spades). am i correct in this. thank you

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Do you mind helping me in this please. if I flip a fair coin 3 times, what is the probability that the coin comes up heads an odd number of times.

Comment: The sample space is: {TTT, TTH, THT, THH, HTT, HTH, HHT, HHH}. Of these only TTH, THT, HTT and HHH have an odd number of heads. So, probability is $\frac{4}{8}$

Comment: Another way is to consider that in 3 tosses of a coin, to get an odd number of heads mean getting either 1 head or 3 heads. P(1 head) = $\binom{3}{1}(\frac{1}{2})^3$ and P(3 heads) = $\binom{3}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^3$